# How to disable "." button in numeric input on screen keyboard Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, input, windows-phone

I want to use numeric input in Windows Phone 8. But I only want to used Numeric one with no char "." in it.

[image]

This is the picture of numeric input that I used in windows phone 8, what im gonna to do is disable the "." in the bottom left of the picture. How i can do that ? Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use like this---

```
<TextBox .... InputScope="Digits" ....>  in xaml
```

This will still add the '.' key in the keyboard. To prevent users from typing it you add the KeyUp event to the TextBox and do the following:
in code behind--

```
private void KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
if (txt.Text.Contains('.'))
{
    txt.Text = txt.Text.Replace(".", "");
    txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just write the following code on key down event of the TextBox control

```
private void YourTextBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

{

if (e.PlatformKeyCode == 190)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, which does ignore the press of the "." key:

XAML:

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number" KeyDown="TextBox_OnKeyDown" />
```

C#:

```
private void TextBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), "[0-9]");
}
```